# Protected route is redirecting before API response arrives

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, react-redux, react-router

I am using Protected Route to redirect a user to subscription page if the subscription is ended. But Route is not waiting for the api response to arrive.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { subscriptionData = {} } = useContext(AppContext) || {};
  return (
    <Route
      render={(props) => {
        if (subscriptionData && subscriptionData.active) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        }
        return <Redirect to={`${ROUTE_PREFIX}/settings/billing`} />;
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

API call is going in action -

```
export const getSubscription = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const url = `/subscription/`;
  await handleAjaxCalls(dispatch, 'GET', url, null, GET_SUBSCRIPTION);
};
```

The API call is mader from `useEffect()` of `App.js` file. 
When the API call is going on `subscriptionData` is empty `{}` the redirection is happening to `${ROUTE_PREFIX}/settings/billing` page. Any help to restrict this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What API response? There isn't any asynchronous code in your snippet to await on. Does your `subscriptionData` have a "pending" state you could check?

Comment: @DrewReese - edited the question and added the API call. API call is going within an action and redux is handling the data.

Comment: Does your `subscriptionData` have a "pending" state, or any status, you could check?

Comment: @DrewReese - Yes. Now I am able to handle it with a pending state. Thanks.